variables globales wordpress
estoy trabajando con una página en wordpress, la cual por directriz de la empresa, se me indicó que debo usar un indice luego de la ruta del sitio, por ejemplo en mi caso, de ser www.misitio.cl pasa a ser www.misitio.cl/intranet
cree la página y todo bien.
el problema es que requiero usar una variable global para modificar /intranet, esto con el fin de tener mi código tanto en producción como en QA, y no tener que cambiar a mano cada url.
en functions.php tengo esto:
 global $raizVariable;
 $raizVariable = array('raiz' => '/intranetQA');

en las páginas de front, no tengo problemas en usar esta variable, pero en back, cuando proceso un formulario, debo instanciar wp-load.php antes de podar usarlos, yo uso este inlcude:
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/intranetQA/wp-load.php');

requiero poder cambiar /intranetQA por mi variable global, si lo hago así:
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $raizVariable . '/wp-load.php');

tengo este error:
Undefined variable $raizVariable
he probado varias formas sin exito.
alguien me podría ayudar por favor ;(
Trate de utilizar variables de entorno, como se hace tradicionalmente en php
cree un archivo en la raíz llamado .env
RAIZ_INDEX=/intranetQA

Luego, para que wordpress pueda leer .env, dentro de wp-config agregue la siguiente funcion:
    function loadEnv($path) {
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        throw new Exception("El archivo .env no existe en la ruta especificada.");
    }

    $lines = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if (strpos(trim($line), '#') === 0) {
            continue;
        }

        list($name, $value) = explode('=', $line, 2);

        $name = trim($name);
        $value = trim($value);

        $value = trim($value, '"');

        putenv("$name=$value");
        $_ENV[$name] = $value;
        $_SERVER[$name] = $value;
    }
}
loadEnv(__DIR__ . '/.env');
define('RAIZ_INDEX', getenv('RAIZ_INDEX') ?: '');

y en la página donde proceso datos, llamo así:
$envValue = getenv('RAIZ_INDEX');
echo '<p>Valor de RAIZ_INDEX: ' . $envValue . '</p>';


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! esto es php y se ejecuta todo en el back.. como que tenes diferencias??? y otra cosa, no podes usar variables de entorno y asi solucionar todo de una?

en wordpress se trabaja diferente que como php puro. en wordpress toda la configuración va en wp-config.php, entonces wordpress, en todas sus páginas visibles, se usa de forma automatica la llamada al wp-load, pero cuando procesas datos en el back, debes llamar al wp-load antes de usar cualquier tipo de variable nativa de wordpress.
y ahí está el problema, que no me deja usar variables sin esa condicional

Tal vez no te estoy entendiendo.. pero todo esta en el mismo servidor.. o vos tenes un back fuera de tu instalacion de wp?

Está todo dentro del mismo servidor, ahí agregué a la pregunta lo que hice para obtener la variable de forma normal.

Pero, ¿será siempre intranet o se trata de un valor que puede cambiar según ciertos criterios? Si es siempre el mismo valor lo mejor es configurarlo usando permalinks.

Primero, la respuesta va en el campo respuesta.. nos encantan las autorespuestas!!! segundo, eso no parece un parche, parece lo que te comente en mi primer comentario y suena perfecto... porque decis que es un parche??? Borra la respuesta de la pregunta, y ponela como respuesta!!!!

ohh super gracias :)

SOLUCIÓN.
Al ser esta variable global cambiable, costó demasiado dar con la solución más propia de wordpress, por lo que la solución que tuve fue:
como trabajo en un ambiente dockerizado, se guardó la variable dentro del docker-compose y se llamó desde wp-config
algo así:
en docker:
environment:
  - RAIZ_INDEX=/intranetQA

y en wp-config:
// Variable global
define('raiz', getenv('RAIZ_INDEX'));

